# Optimal algorithm for smallest possible number evenly divisible by all numbers below X

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

This is my attempt to find a well performing algorithm for problem 5 Project Euler - find the smalles possible number that is evenly divisible x and all the numbers below x.

I've tried using one loop make #s and another to test if that number is evenly divisible by x and all #s below x

```
System.out.println("This program finds the smallest positive "
                + "number that");
        System.out.println("is evenly divisible by all of the numbers "
                + "from 1 to N.");
        System.out.print("Enter N: ");
        int N=kb.nextInt();
        long bigN=1;
        for(int i=1;i<=N;i++){
            bigN=bigN*i;
            /*bigN serves as a definite end for our loop
            when trying to find all #s divisible from 1 to n
            */
        }
        long smallestAnswer=bigN;
        int count=0;
        for(long i=1;i<=bigN;i++){//# being tested
            for(int j=1;j<=N;j++){//test
                if(i%j==0){
                    count++;
                }
                if(count==N && i<smallestAnswer){
                smallestAnswer=i;//should catch only the first/smallest answer
                break;
                }
            }
            count=0;
        }
        System.out.printf("\nThe smallest # evenly divisible by all of the "
                + "numbers from 1 to N");
        System.out.printf("\nis %,d\n",smallestAnswer);
    }
```

The code works. No run/compileTime errors. It's just far too slow. If the user enters a # bigger than 11, the code just freezes basically

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking to improve running code belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Andreas I don|t agree. This is pure algorithmics. It is not a question of a meer code review.

Comment: Where: study the codereview help desk much much more than the help desk here. Learn how to ask questions that are in the scope of the community.

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov Then for questions about algorithms, use [Computational Science Stack Exchange](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @GhostCat by giving example solution he has proven he has made an effort.

Comment: @GhostCat currently stackoverflow has 100k questions in the tag algorithms. What makes this specific question to be "outside of the scope of the comunity" .

Comment: @GhostCat true :) we don't have to agree.

Comment: What research have you done to find the last common multiple of those numbers?  Your coding solution shows no attempt to implement anything except incremental brute force.  We expect that you've already tried to research this on your own, but you haven't used any of the previous questions on this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using a brute-force algorithm. Challenges, like found on Project Euler, are more often challenges to find the right algorithm, not merely challenges to write the code.

The challenge here is to find the **least common multiple** (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple)), of all the numbers from 1 to X.

Example: If X is 10, one way to solve it is to identify the divisors:

```
 1 = 1
 2 = 2
 3 = 3     
 4 = 2^2
 5 = 5
 6 = 2 * 3
 7 = 7
 8 = 2^3
 9 = 3^2
10 = 2 * 5
```

The divisors for the least common multiple is therefore:

```
1 * 2^3 * 3^2 * 5 * 7  =  1 * 8 * 9 * 5 * 7 = 2520
```

Since this is a **challenge** for you to solve, I'll leave the coding to you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure why you're struggling with performance.

```
$ date && X 20 && date
Tue Jun 25 13:18:13 CDT 2019
N: 20
232792560 is divisible by all numbers 1 to 20
Tue Jun 25 13:18:16 CDT 2019
```

3 seconds for N == 20.

You are doing extra math for each number you check -- a LOT of extra math. Instead of doing the check for each number 1 to N, first, you could do from 2 to N, as all numbers are divisible by 1. But more importantly, you're doing ALL even if one fails. If you turn that portion around, breaking out of your "does this number work" code as soon as a modulus check fails. On N=20, this will save you 18 checks on all odd numbers.

You could also gain more improvements. The number must be even. So if n>1, you could start at 2 and increment by 2 instead of one. If n>=3, you could actually start at 6 and increment by 6, saving a LOT of math. And if n>=4, you could start at 12 and increment by 12.

For reference, here is my implementation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    long trying = 1;
    bool found = false;

    while(!found) {
        found = true;
        ++trying;

        for (long checkDivide = 2; checkDivide <= n; +checkDivide) {
            if (trying % checkDivide != 0) {
                found = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%ld is divisible by all numbers 1 to %d\n", trying, n);

    return 0;
}
```

I skipped asking for input and just put the value on the command line.

Note that reversing the check also is probably more efficient. That is, start checking at n and work down to 2. X % 20 is going to fail more often than X % 2. I'm not using sufficient time check resolution to be sure how much more efficient it is.

Comment: Thank you so much. I just remade my code, but this time I used booleans and the break and I got the answer so quickly. What I've read in this thread is correct, it's not only about finding the right answer. It's about doing it efficiently and cutting out all that extra math has made my code much more efficient. Thanks again